# Contact Us Page

Tags: magento2, email, contact-us, contact-form

Currently our contact page doesn't work.

We installed MailChimp in hopes that it work link, but apparently that's only for the order confirmations etc

I tried it as it is, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I can't find the email I entered in the /var/log/maillog, so I'm confused.

How can I get it to work?

I'm using Centos 7 with Vesta CP installed.

I am using Magento version 2.2

On my contact us page, looks like the below. However no email is received to the email set in my admin.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: message sent notification coming after submitting contact us form?

Comment: could you provide more information ? what issue are you facing, does it show contact us form or page ? do you get confirmation message, what version of magento are you using etc. providing more detail will help to give you some solution.

Comment: Updating the question now

Comment: try debug mode enable & search for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unofrtuantly, I did not get this working.

I am assuming it is an issue within the server not sending the mails, rather than Magento itself.

I solved this by installing a SMTP plugin and setting some Gmail account settings.